# Pandas dataframe returning double (dotted values)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a Pandas dataframe from which I'm retrieving data like:

```
print str(d_f.ix[i]['ColumnName'])
```

The data in this column is just integer values, like:

```
1
2
3
```

But they are printed as:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
```

How to force printing original (int / not dotted) values?

Comment: How about `print str(int(d_f.ix[i]['ColumnName']))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.astype` method on the series

```
print str(d_f.ix[i]['ColumnName'].astype(int))
```